# How can I aggregate data into a single row within my tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr

**Current Code:**

```
ROW_tidy <- data %>%
  group_by(year, country) %>%
  summarize("Suicides Per 100K Population" = (sum(suicides_no)/sum(population)) * 100000)
```

**Which Produces this Tibble (only first 3 row):**

```
    year    country             Suicides Per 100K Population
    1985    Antigua and Barbuda 0.00000000
    1985    Argentina           7.33828458
    1985    Australia          12.77939914
```

However, I'd like to edit this tibble so that it delineates US Suicides per 100K population and Rest of World Suicides per 100K population (aggregating/averaging all other countries suicide/100k populate rate) for each year. How would I do this?

Comment: Please do provide some toy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can group by whether the country is the USA or any other country (otherwise I think you'd send a distorted message averaging those rates without respect for each country's population).
Then you can use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to create columns for your data rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  group_by(year, country_group = ifelse(country == "USA", "USA", "rest_of_world")) %>%
  summarize(suicides = (sum(suicides_no)/sum(population)) * 100000) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = country_group, values_from = suicides, names_prefix = "suicides_per100k_in_")
```